# Ionic Cordova FCM Error node:844

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I get the below error when I try to run or to build android, after installing 
`cordova-plugin-fcm` Plugin.

`(node:844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
(node:844) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exxit code.`

have anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the android platform:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

Then reinstall:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

Now you should be able to install cordova-plugin-fcm without errors:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Try with a new project and add the platform with android@6.4.0